# Is there a way to get in and out Escobar International without our weapons being removed?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-vice-city

I'm about to play [Check Out At The Check In](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Check_Out_At_The_Check_In), and I want to know: Is there a way to get in and out Escobar International Airport without your weapons being removed?

A quote from the GTA Wiki article:

> The player can still get their weapons while inside the airport by walking close to the windows at the front of the terminal. **Alternatively, the player can use a vehicle to jump over the metal detectors**.

That's the best way to get in (and it worked), but how do you get out without triggering the metal detectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought I remembered I had a sniper inside.

As the description reads, you will have a sniper inside the terminal to kill the target. If you need a weapon you can quickly snipe a guard for a pistol.

**There's no way to exit the terminal without triggering the detectors**(unless you manage to get a car inside and then out in some freaky stunt) but I don't see what the problem is, as when you're going out your weapons will be removed from you and be placed on the outside of the terminal, so you simply go out and collect your weapons.

I'd usually park my car next to one door, go trough, kill the target, go out trough the other door, collect my weapons, get in my car and run.

Comment: The problem was that every car that I left outside was removed when the mission is taken, so after taking the briefcase I would need to wait for a cop car to arrive and rush to take it with a UZI. Because I touched the metal detector the weapons were placed outside and the "take + select" was not that fast that I could get run over or shoot to death.